# bootstrap row height the rest of the space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How do I set a row height to the rest of the page height using bootstrap?

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="height:20px">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          header
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="height:{rest of the space}">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            body
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```